# How can I scrape data from a url within a target url and amend everything to a single data frame in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data points from one webpage (A), but then scrape data from each individual data point's own webpage and combine all of the data into a single data frame for easy viewing.

This is for a daily data frame with four columns: Team, Pitcher, ERA, WHIP. The ERA and WHIP are found within the specific pitcher's url. For the data below, I have managed to scrape the team name as well as the starting pitcher name and organized both into a data frame (albeit incorrectly).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
targetUrl = 'http://www.baseball-reference.com/previews/'
targetUrl_response = requests.get(targetUrl, timeout=5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(targetUrl_response.content, "html.parser")    

teams = []
pitchers = []

for i in soup.find_all('tr'):
    if i.find_all('strong'):
        for link in i.find_all('strong'):
            if not re.findall(r'MLB Debut',link.text):
                teams.append(link.text)
            if i.find_all('a'):
                for link in i.find_all('a'):
                    if not re.findall(r'Preview',link.text):
                        pitchers.append(link.text)
print (df)
```

I'd like to add code to follow each pitcher's webpage, scrape the ERA and WHIP, then amend the data to the same data frame as team and pitcher name. Is this even possible?

Output so far:

```
                     0
Aaron Sanchez      TOR
CC Sabathia        NYY
Steven Matz        NYM
Zach Eflin         PHI
Lucas Giolito      CHW
Eduardo Rodriguez  BOS
Brad Keller        KCR
Adam Plutko        CLE
Julio Teheran      ATL
Jon Lester         CHC
Clayton Kershaw    LAD
Zack Greinke       ARI
Jon Gray           COL
Drew Pomeranz      SFG
```

Answer (score 1):

Few things off the bat (see what I did there :-) ) the sports-reference.com pages are dynamic. You're able to pull SOME of the tables straight forward, but tif there are multiple tables, you'll find them under comment tags within the html source. So that might be an issue later if you want more data from the page.

The second thing is I notice you are pulling `<tr>` tags, which means there are `<table>` tags, and pandas can do the heavy work for you as opposed to iterating through with bs4. It's a simple `pd.read_html()` function. HOWEVER, it won't pull out those links, just strictly the text. So in this case, iterating with BeautifulSoup is the way to go (I'm just mentioning it for future reference).

There's still more work to do as a couple of the guys didn't have links/return era or whip. And you'll also have to account for if a guy is traded or change leagues, there might be multiple ERAs for the same 2019 season. But this should get you going:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
targetUrl = 'http://www.baseball-reference.com/previews/'
targetUrl_response = requests.get(targetUrl, timeout=5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(targetUrl_response.content, "html.parser")    

teams = []
pitchers = []
era_list = []
whip_list = []

for i in soup.find_all('tr'):
    if i.find_all('strong'):
        for link in i.find_all('strong'):
            if not re.findall(r'MLB Debut',link.text):
                teams.append(link.text)
            if i.find_all('a'):
                for link in i.find_all('a'):
                    if not re.findall(r'Preview',link.text):
                        try:
                            url_link = link['href']
                            pitcher_table = pd.read_html(url_link)[0]
                            pitcher_table = pitcher_table[(pitcher_table['Year'] == '2019') & (pitcher_table['Lg'].isin(['AL', 'NL']))]

                            era = round(pitcher_table.iloc[0]['ERA'],2)
                            whip = round(pitcher_table.iloc[0]['WHIP'],2)

                        except:
                            era = 'N/A'
                            whip = 'N/A'
                        pitchers.append(link.text)
                        era_list.append(era)
                        whip_list.append(whip)
                        print ('%s\tERA: %s\tWHIP: %s' %(link.text, era, whip))

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(pitchers, teams, era_list, whip_list)), columns = ['Pitcher', ',Team', 'ERA', 'WHIP'])
print (df)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
              Pitcher Team    ERA  WHIP
0      Walker Lockett  NYM  23.14  2.57
1        Jake Arrieta  PHI   4.12  1.38
2         Logan Allen  SDP      0  0.71
3     Jimmy Yacabonis  BAL    4.7  1.44
4     Clayton Richard  TOR   7.46  1.74
5      Glenn Sparkman  KCR   3.62  1.25
6        Shane Bieber  CLE   3.86  1.08
7       Carson Fulmer  CHW   6.35  1.94
8         David Price  BOS   3.39   1.1
9        Jesse Chavez  TEX    N/A   N/A
10  Jordan Zimmermann  DET   6.03  1.37
11       Max Scherzer  WSN   2.62  1.06
12    Trevor Richards  MIA   3.54  1.25
13          Max Fried  ATL   4.03  1.34
14     Adbert Alzolay  CHC   2.25  0.75
15     Marco Gonzales  SEA   4.38  1.37
16        Zach Davies  MIL   3.06  1.36
17    Trevor Williams  PIT   4.12  1.19
18        Gerrit Cole  HOU   3.54  1.02
19        Blake Snell  TBR    4.4  1.24
20        Kyle Gibson  MIN   4.18  1.25
21      Chris Bassitt  OAK   3.64  1.17
22      Jack Flaherty  STL   4.24  1.18
23     Ross Stripling  LAD   3.08  1.17
24         Robbie Ray  ARI   3.87  1.34
25   Chi Chi Gonzalez  COL    N/A   N/A
26  Madison Bumgarner  SFG   4.28  1.24
27        Tyler Mahle  CIN   4.17   1.2
28      Andrew Heaney  LAA   5.68  1.14
```